# Can't update Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to update *Visual Studio 2017 RC from 15.0.25909.2 to 15.0.25914.0* and when I hit **Update** button it throws following error

> Path to vsix file 'update' is invalid or you don't have required access permissions.  Please check the path is valid and you have required access permissions.
>
> Usage: VSIXInstaller.exe [/quiet] ...
>   ...

1. I ran it as *Administrator* unfortunately same issue occurs.
2. Recorded Screen-cast is [here](http://www.screencast.com/t/a0I0eQn8E)

Comment: Have you trying updating with the Visual Studio Installer?

Comment: I'm not aware of that installer can update the Visual Studio also tried to locate where it might be but no luck.  I tried to run it from **Add/Remove programs** but it has only **Uninstall** option.  I'm assuming that you are not suggesting to re-run the original installer, if that's the case please let me know.  Thank you for your time!

Comment: Look for `Visual Studio Installer` in your programs, the one you used to install the workloads.

Comment: I was going to write you it is not exist in **Start Menu** then saw that in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer` path.  THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: Don't thank me yet. You may still get an error. VS 2017 RC is *very* unstable. You may have to uninstall it, clean up any leftover folders, then try again

Comment: Exactly!   Many of following messages `[232c:0020][2016-12-09T09:31:36] VSIX installer does not exist at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe'.
[232c:0020][2016-12-09T09:31:36] Package '...' failed to uninstall. Return code: 2` but **VSIXInstaller** is in that path.  Ran again and it became single error, then ran from the command prompt and it worked.  At least it is updated.  Thanks!

Comment: Write this as an answer. A lot of people are going to hit this problem.

Comment: OK will do, thank you again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [@panagiotis-kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) I did be able to solve the issue.  For those who may hit the same wall, here is the steps I followed.

1. You need to locate **Visual Studio Installer** which is not in **Start Menu**!.  You may find it at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe`
2. Once you run it, click on **Update** button.
3. It will probably give you errors like this

   > [232c:0020][2016-12-09T09:31:36] VSIX installer does not exist at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe'. 
   >   [232c:0020][2016-12-09T09:31:36] Package '...' failed to uninstall. Return code: 2

   *Check the path and make sure **VSIXInstaller.exe** is there*
4. Once again, click on **Update** button.

   *this time, it will throw a different error and if you open the log file that upgrade process provides, it should have full command details which is/are failing*

   > **WARNING  following code was in "my" log file and I placed it here "only for demonstration purpose", do not use it directly, check your log file to get correct failing errors**
   >
   > "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe" /q /s /admin /appidinstallpath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /logFile:"C:\Users\ciler\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20161209094800_001_GitHub.VisualStudio.log" /skuName:Enterprise /skuVersion:15.0.25928.0 /appidname:displayName /uninstall:c3d3dc68-c977-411f-b3e8-03b0dccf7dfc
5. Run that command in your **Command Prompt** and make sure you change the `/logfile:` filename in order to eliminate overwriting the existing one.

Comment: I can't until it stays there for 2 days.  More information is in [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6045/214252)