# Update Visual Studio 2017 from Visual Studio 2015.3 and 2017 rc

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017

Good morning,
I have installed in my PC (Windows 10) Visual Studio 2015.3 and Visual Studio 2017 RC, both of them with a lot of things installed on.
Now, that Visual Studio 2017 is finally out, I want to have only and don't have Visual Studio 2017 RC or the "old" Visual Studio 2015.
I search over [internet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio) and I find how to have an off-line installation of Visual Studio 2017. Now I don't know which is the best solution between:

1. Uninstall All plugin like resharper or so on, restart, uninstall Visual Studio 2017 RC, Restart, Uninstall Visual Studio 2015.3, restart, install Visual Studio 2017, install all plugin
2. Install Visual Studio 2017, update all plugin, uninstall Visual Studio 2017 rc, uninstall Visual Studio 2015.3

Or other...is there someone that have a simil issue?

Thanks

Comment: @HansPassant: the RC can be upgraded to RTM, no need to uninstall it.

Comment: can != wise, I never not had a problem with betas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VS 2015:
You don't have to uninstall VS 2015, and if you want to uninstall it, you can do it later, because it is completely independent from VS 2017.

VS 2017 RC:
Additionally to the update, of course it is possible to do a fresh install. 
This is what I would do at least for my main development system.
Updates can be more error-prone than new installations (Consider this for example):
[Can't update Visual Studio 2017 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062187/cant-update-visual-studio-2017-rc?rq=1)

If you prefer a fresh install I would take your sequence 1 (but let VS 2015, at least until VS 2017 was successful installed).

Edit: Just install the current version of Resharper instead of using old versions. Resharper for VS 2017 was not released the same day as VS 2017 itself, but some weeks later.

Answer (score 3):

First: versions of Visual Studio work side by side, they do not upgrade. If you wish to remove VS2015 then you need to uninstall it.

Second: if you start up your VS2017 RC it will prompt you to update. The updater will upgrade from RC to RTM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So in your opinion this list are correct? 1. Uninstall plugin 2. Uninstall VS 2015.3 3. Download a off line installer of VS 2017 4.Install Visual Studio 2017 that will update the RC 5. Reinstall all plugin...it sounds good?

Comment: @pinguinone If you need to use offline installer, then yes (the full offline installer is huge, unless you need all the emulators etc. just using the web install will be quicker).